# Parameterized Type Aliases - Clarification Requested

Tags: scala, types, alias, type-parameter

Consider the following 2 type alias declarations:

```
type Id[A] = A
type Swap[m[_, _], a, b] = m[b, a]
```

I'm having a difficult time understanding exactly what these mean. The first one seems to define *'Id'* as an alias for the abstract simple type *'A'*. But *Id* is parameterized by the same abstract type. So I'm not understanding exactly what *Id* is and how it would be used. Perhaps someone could provide some examples?

The second example comes from the language spec and is accompanied with the following text:

> ... Type constructors are another example, as one can write type Swap[m[_,
>   _], a,b] = m[b, a], but there is no syntax to write the corresponding anonymous type function directly.

So, again, I'm confused as to what *Swap* is actually aliasing and how this or a similar declaration would be useful (and how it would be used). Also, what is an ***anonymous type function***?

Thanks.

Comment: Sample usage of `Swap` - def swap[A, B](tuple: Tuple2[A, B]): Swap[Tuple2, A, B] = input._2 -> input._1

Comment: `Id` is called identity type, you can find a lot of examples of usage in `scalaz` sources

Comment: @Maxim, @Archeg Thanks for your comments. Swap makes a lot more sense to me now. Seems that you can look at it as a _normal_ alias, but in this case, the type is defined in terms of the type parameters used in the declaration of the alias. `Id` is still mysterious to me in that it is a parameterized type that is declared to be equivalent to the type used as the type parameter.  I've looked at a lot of the usages in scalaz, but it's still not clicking. Looks like a magical way to return a value of type A that somehow satisfies the requirement that it be of type `Id[A]`.

Comment: You can also see some usages of Id in this blog post: http://milessabin.com/blog/2012/05/10/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-2/

Comment: As for the anonymous type functions I think they mean something like `val a: ({ type F[T[_,_],A,B] = T[B,A] })#F[Tuple2, Int, String] = ("foo", 7)`. But this is more useful in combination with context bounds for instance.

Comment: @Jasper-M Thanks for the help.